# How to get the index of the current element in for each in c++?

Tags: loops, foreach, c++17

while using a "for each" loop in c++, I want to store the indices of each element in another vector but I couldn't get these indices.
Is there any way to get it by using "for each" loop, not the "iterative" loop?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cout.tie(nullptr);cin.tie(nullptr);

    int n, mn = INT_MAX, mx = INT_MIN, res = INT_MAX;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int>a(n), vmin, vmax;
    for(auto& i:a){
        cin>>i;
        mx=max(mx, i);
        mn=min(mn, i);
    }

    for(auto& i:a){
        if(i==mn)
                    vmin.push_back(i);
        else if(i==mx)
                    vmax.push_back(i);
    }

    for(auto& i:vmax){
        auto l = lower_bound(vmin.begin(), vmin.end(), i);

        if(l != vmax.end())
            res=min(res, *l - i);
    }

    for(auto& i:vmin){
        auto l = lower_bound(vmax.begin(), vmax.end(), i);

        if(l != vmin.end())
            res=min(res, *l - i);
    }

    cout<<res;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I want to store the indices of each element but this will store the current element itself not the index of the current element

```
for(auto& i:a){
    if(i==mn)
        vmin.push_back(i);
    else if(i==mx)
        vmax.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: `auto index = &i - &a.front()`. (Works for `std::vector` which guarantees contiguous storage.) Though personally, when I need an access to the index as well as the element, I write a plain old loop over indexes; this gives the reader a heads-up.

Comment: Alternatively: `size_t index = 0; for (auto& i: a) { DoThingsWith(i, index); ++index;}`

Comment: If you are okay with boost, you could use `boost::adaptors::indexed`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html
Example: https://godbolt.org/z/r57zYGYoE